# Pandas convert column to float with a $symbol

Tags: pandas

I have an object column(item_price) and I want to convert it in a float column but I can´t not do it with the symbol $...can anyone help me??

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
chipo['item_price'] = chipo['item_price'].str.lstrip('$')
```

and then convert it float.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
chipo['item_price'] = chipo['item_price'].str.replace('$', '', regex=False).astype(float)
```